# How to define allow_destroy and :dependent => :destroy in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested, dependencies

Given the following database model, **how and where** would you define the deletion relationships between the models? I figured out the basic table association setup but when I want to add dependencies to enable the **deletion of nested objects** I get lost.

[image: Database relationship model]

Here is the relationship model I created.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :studies
end

class Study < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :internships
  belongs_to :student, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
  belongs_to :subject
  belongs_to :university, :class_name => "Facility", :foreign_key => "facility_id"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subject, :university, :locations
end

class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :studies
end

class Internship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :study
  belongs_to :company, :class_name => "Facility", :foreign_key => 'facility_id'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company, :study
end

class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :internships
  has_many :locations
  has_many :studies
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :facility
end
```

Where would you put `:dependent => :destroy` and `:allow_destroy => true` to enable the following scenarios? I do not want to confuse you. Therefore, I leave out my tryings.

**Internship scenario:** A user wants to delete an internship.

- Its associated company (facility) can be deleted if the company is not related to another internship.
- If so, the locations of the associated company can be deleted.
- The related study will not be affected.

**Study scenario**: A user wants to delete a study.

- Its associated subject can be deleted if no other study refers to this subject.
- Its associated university (facility) can be deleted if no other study refers to this university.
- Its associated internships can be deleted. The company can only be deleted if no other internship refers to it.

I am totally unsure whether I can add `:dependent => :destroy` only after `has_one` and `has_many` or also after `belongs_to`.

---

Edit: To simplify the problem please stick to the following (reduced) example implementation.

```
class Study < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subject, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :studies, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

In my view I provide the following link.

```
<%= link_to "Destroy", study, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
```

The path is based on the named routes given by a restful configuration in `routes.rb`.

```
resources :studies
resources :subjects
```

The study will be deleted when I click the link - the subjects stays untouched. Why?

Comment: You can add `:dependent => :destroy` to all three

Comment: Could you please state where exactly to put it?

Answer (score 2):

I think your relations are the wrong way around here...
The `accepts_nested_attributes_for` should be declared on the model that `has_many` for the model that it `has_many` of. Also, in your example, destroying the subject would enforce `dependent_destroy` on the many `studies`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `:dependent => :destroy` to all three but I'm not sure if that'll give you enough power to do the checks required before determining whether an associated object should be destroyed.

You have a few options.

Add a before_destroy callback on each model that raises an exception or stops the delete from occurring.

```
class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :internships
  has_many :locations
  has_many :studies

  def before_destroy
    raise SomethingException if internships.any? || ...
    # or
    errors.add(...
  end
end
```

or do it silently by overriding destroy

```
class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :internships
  has_many :locations
  has_many :studies

  def destroy
    return false if internships.any || ...
    super
  end
end
```

*Note: this is basically meant for guidance only and may not be the correct way of overriding destroy etc...*

Comment: The checks are not the main problem. `before_destroy` can take care of it. - But try to destroy for example a Subject in the Internship scenario. Where do I have to put the `:dependent => :destroy` ..?

Comment: I mean that you probably wouldn't use `:dependent => :destroy` at all in this scenario. Only if you always want the associated object(s) destroyed as opposed to if you'd like them destroyed conditionally. So I would use the `before_destroy` callbacks instead.

Comment: I thought, whenever `before_destroy` returns `false` for a specific object/model, the deletion process will continue nevertheless. Do you think that is possible?